# PHPUnit 4.1 error - Failed asserting that a traversable contains 'Bitcoin' with assertContains

Tags: php, phpunit, simplexml

I have a method that I'm testing that outputs XML.  I have the following assertions in my test (names changed due to NDA):

```
// arrange

$service = new Service($entityManager);

// act

$results = $service->doThing();
$xml = simplexml_load_string($results);

// assert

$this->assertContains('Bitcoin', $xml->item[0]->paymentStatus);
$this->assertContains('Credit Card', $xml->item[1]->paymentStatus);
```

`paymentStatus` is a string in both cases.  One is simply:

```
<paymentStatus>Paid with Bitcoin</paymentStatus>
```

the other is

```
<paymentStatus>Paid with Credit Card</paymentStatus>
```

Since the `paymentStatus` contains a string, that should be considered traversable, correct?  Then why can't it 'see' the Bitcoin/Credit Card portions of those strings?  I've verified the output manually.  The strings with those values *are* part of my result XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out to be a known bug/intended behavior that hasn't been addressed in a decade: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=29500

:facepalm: